# Invoking multiple ajax requests on the same view in a portlet leads to ViewExpiredException

Tags: java, jsf, portlet, viewexpiredexception

I am working in Portal application build using JSF and Ajax.
All the pagecodes are in request scope. We have a page with 2 portlets and in one of the portlet we use ajax to rerender components.

When we do such rerendering we are able to modify it 3 times and when we submit the form it gets submitted but if we rerender more than 3 times and when we try to submit it gives a view expired exception and the page reloads with all values cleared up.

Currently there is no entry in web.xml for number of logical views. So I guess its defaulted to 15. If I had an entry to this and set the value to 30 I am able to rerender for around 10 times but more than that it gives a view expired exception.(This might occupy a lot of memory)

Can you please let me know how I can solve this with optimal utilization of views and also find how many viewsa are being utilized by each portlet?
Stack Trace :

```
[12/8/11 16:45:43:304 CST] 00000051 servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet CreateCustomer in application CustomerDetailsEAR. Exception created : javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.portlet.PortletException: viewId:/create/CreateCustomerView.jsp - View /create/CreateCustomerView.jsp could not be restored.
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.doDispatch(PortletServlet.java:361)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:82)
    at com.ibm.isclite.container.collaborator.PortletServletCollaborator.doDispatch(PortletServletCollaborator.java:143)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.rrd.RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.doDispatch(RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.java:60)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.CacheCollaborator.doDispatch(CacheCollaborator.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorImpl.doDispatch(PortletServletCollaboratorImpl.java:121)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.dispatch(PortletServlet.java:208)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:165)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1655)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1595)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:104)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:895)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:932)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:500)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:673)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.invoke(PortletInvokerImpl.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:76)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.PortletInvokerCacheCollaborator.doAction(PortletInvokerCacheCollaborator.java:50)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:65)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.invoke(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:313)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.doInvoke(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:101)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.invokePMI(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:163)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.doInvoke(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.doAction(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:62)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:65)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.action(PortletInvokerImpl.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerImpl.doAction(PortletContainerImpl.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:78)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.ExtCollaborator.doAction(ExtCollaborator.java:58)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:65)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.CacheInvokerCollaborator.doAction(CacheInvokerCollaborator.java:76)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:65)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerImpl.processPortletAction(PortletContainerImpl.java:152)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.pcinvoker.PortletInvokerImpl$1.run(PortletInvokerImpl.java:59)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:251)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.pcinvoker.PortletInvokerImpl.invokeProcessAction(PortletInvokerImpl.java:55)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletInvokerImpl$3.invoke(PortletInvokerImpl.java:115)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.invoke(PortletInvokerImpl.java:175)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.invokeProcessAction(PortletInvokerImpl.java:113)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.event.ActionEvent.execute(ActionEvent.java:78)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.event.EventQueueManager.processEventLoop(EventQueueManager.java:112)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.PortletContainerImpl.performEvents(PortletContainerImpl.java:206)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.PortletContainerImpl.performEvents(PortletContainerImpl.java:298)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPActionPhase.processPortlets(WPActionPhase.java:2644)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPActionPhase.execute(WPActionPhase.java:668)
    at com.ibm.wps.state.phases.AbstractActionPhase.next(AbstractActionPhase.java:130)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.callPortal(Servlet.java:855)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.doGet(Servlet.java:617)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.doPost(Servlet.java:888)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.doFilter(Servlet.java:1257)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.ContentHandlerCleanup.doFilter(ContentHandlerCleanup.java:648)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:93)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.service(Servlet.java:1248)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1655)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1595)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.ExtendedLocaleFilter.doFilter(ExtendedLocaleFilter.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.friendly.servlet.FriendlySelectionFilter.doFilter(FriendlySelectionFilter.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.wps.mappingurl.impl.URLAnalyzer.doFilter(URLAnalyzer.java:352)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.VirtualPortalFilter.doFilter(VirtualPortalFilter.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.wps.state.filter.StateCleanup.doFilter(StateCleanup.java:94)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:895)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:932)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:500)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3810)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:183)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:272)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1550)
Caused by: javax.portlet.PortletException: viewId:/create/CreateCustomerView.jsp - View /create/CreateCustomerView.jsp could not be restored.
```

Comment: You don't have the stacktrace?

Comment: @gurung: the stacktrace of a `ViewExpiredException` is usually not helpful.

Comment: What JSF impl/version? This sounds like as every ajax render is implicitly creating a bunch of views instead of reusing them. Perhaps the `javax.faces.ViewState` hidden field is not sent at all. What happens if you set `javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD` to `client`? I'm not sure how portlets play a role here, so I'm not posting this as an answer. Also check ajax requests using Firebug/Chrome/Fiddler2.

Comment: In a portlal application each portlet seem to have a view. So if a page has 10 portlets it uses 10 views. When I tried setting state_saviing_Method to client does work fine. Is there any other impact of setting it to client?Can you also explain why it does not work with server?

Comment: I also think like setting it to client will make the client side heavier

Comment: Do we have a way to fix this issue with javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD set to server side?

Comment: @home this looks like a WebSphere Portal to me. user1090050 can you conform this?

Comment: Yes its is a websphere portal.